# How to evalute prototype js files through rhino script engine in Java

Tags: java, javascript

I am having problems evaluating a script.js file which is dependent of prototype.js. When i am trying to evaluate the script.js file through rhino script engine in java i got Script Exception like "TypeError: $H is not a function, it is java.lang.String.". How do I evaluate the files and how to include prototype.js and to define the prototype objects?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot evaluate prototype.js using Rhino only.
prototype.js have many references to the HTML DOM which is not implemented in Rhino/Java.
For example (from prototype.js):
document.createTextNode('')
The document global object is not defined in Rhino context and createTextNode is not defined too.

The solution is to remove all Objects/Functions from your copy of prototype.js that references the document, window or navigator objects. (assuming your js file does not use them)

Comment: You could also get away with declaring some dummy objects for document, window, navigator and so on. This way you do not have to change prototype.js.

Answer (score 0):

have you evaluated them in the correct order? They need to be evaluated from the bottom up

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [env-js](http://github.com/thatcher/env-js), which is a mock browser environment for Rhino. It's based on [some work by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/) to get JQuery working in Rhino. I wouldn't be surprised if Prototype worked as well.